# What this specific code that uses functionpointer means?

Tags: c

I encountered code that is not clear for me. Therefore I am asking for help.
Can anyone please explain me what the following code means:

```
typedef void (* __data16 functionpointer)(void);

const functionpointer bsloader = (functionpointer)(0x1000);
```

I am not asking about __data16, this is the memory type specifier which informs the compiler that the functionpointer resides in 16bit memory space.

Comment: You already know the first line typedefs a function pointer apparently. What don't you understand about the second?

Comment: Or rather, `__data16` tells that the function pointer is pointing at a function which resides in 16 bit memory space. (A more common non-standard keyword for this would be `near`.) Where the function pointer itself is allocated is probably not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line, you are establishing that `functionpointer` is a pointer to a *function* taking no arguments, returning a `void`. `__data16` is some specifier as you already know.

In the second line, you are *casting* `0x1000` to the type `functionpointer`. `bsloader` is the name you're giving that pointer. It's your job to check that this cast is valid. If it isn't then the behaviour of your program is undefined.

You could then write `bsloader();`. That would invoke the function at address `0x1000`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is creating bsloader as a functionpointer type.  It is making bsloader equal hex 1000 or 4096 in decimal, then casting it as a functionpointer type.

Answer (score 0):

> typedef void (* __data16 functionpointer)(void);

This defines new data type *functionpointer* to declare a function pointer to a function that returns void and takes no arguments. `__data16` has to be a type specifier saying that the address is a two byte value. (i.e `sizeof(__data16)` must return `2`)

> const functionpointer bsloader = (functionpointer)(0x1000);

This uses *functionpointer* (to declare a new function pointer to a function which value is a constant (generally pointless, 1 - because it is explicit)) and its address is given to `0x1000` so make sure there is a function of the same type on that address, otherwise the behavior of your program is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `__data16` is most likely a non-standard extension, telling that the pointer points at functions allocated in 16 bit address space. Such constructs are common on 8 and 16 systems where the address bus width is 16 bits, but there is more memory available outside this address space, aka "banking" or "paging". You'd then have standard 16 bit pointers ("near pointers") and extended 24 or 32 bit pointers ("far pointers"). The old 16 bit MS DOS operative system used such non-standard constructs as well.

Comment: Тhat could be the case.. explains why the address given is only `0x1000` videlicet a 2 byte value. Probably it has something to do with hardware programming.